# Is it posibile to split a daterange in Java into weeks?

Tags: java, date, java-8, calendar, date-range

My Problem is the folowing:
I have a daterange (in java), specified by two `Calendar` objects, one for the start, one for the end.
Now I want to get an List of all weeks which are in this range. A week should be specified by two `Calendar` objects, also one for the start and one for the end.
It is also important, that the start and the end of the whole daterange could be in two different months or even two different years.

Comment: Why you have to use Calendar? Can't you use new Time Api? It contains build in classes and methods for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is implementation of your problem which using new Time Api, read about LocalDate, LocalDateTime, Period etc.

```
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 12).with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 12);

        //number of weeks
        long weekNumber = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(startDate, endDate);

        Map<LocalDate, LocalDate> weeks = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < weekNumber; i++) {
            LocalDate endOfWeek = startDate.plusDays(6);
            weeks.put(startDate, endOfWeek);
            startDate = endOfWeek.plusDays(1);
        }
        for (LocalDate week : weeks.keySet()) {
            LocalDate endOfWeek = weeks.get(week);
            System.out.println("Start of week: " + week + "[" + week.getDayOfWeek() + "]" +
                    " End of week: " + endOfWeek + "[" + endOfWeek.getDayOfWeek() + "]");
        }
```

It prints:

```
Start of week: 2020-12-07[MONDAY] End of week: 2020-12-13[SUNDAY]
Start of week: 2020-12-14[MONDAY] End of week: 2020-12-20[SUNDAY]
Start of week: 2020-12-21[MONDAY] End of week: 2020-12-27[SUNDAY]
Start of week: 2020-12-28[MONDAY] End of week: 2021-01-03[SUNDAY]
Start of week: 2021-01-04[MONDAY] End of week: 2021-01-10[SUNDAY]
```

etc...

edit:

With DateTimeFormatter will be even shorter and day name will display in your language:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[EEEE]");
for (LocalDate startOfWeek : weeks.keySet()) {
    LocalDate endOfWeek = weeks.get(startOfWeek);
    System.out.println("Start of week: " + dateTimeFormatter.format(startOfWeek) +
                    " End of week: " + dateTimeFormatter.format(endOfWeek));
    }
```

Comment: Good answer, except if you live in a country like the US, where weeks start on Sunday, not Monday. The code should use the `WeekFields` class to handle "weeks" correctly.

Comment: Sample code is weird, with dates starting in 2020 and ending in 2019. End date should be after start date to make sense.

Comment: @Andreas to be honest I don't know the time api very well, I wrote it fast enough, as you say it can be improved

Comment: @Andreas yes I made a bug xD I will edit it sorry

Comment: This will not work if you have days that are not exactly divisible by weeks

Answer (score 1):

To do it with the old `Calendar` object, you can do it like shown in first half of answer. To do it with the newer Java Time API added in Java 8, see second half of answer.

---

#### Using old Calendar API

```java
static List<DateRange> weeksCovering(Calendar start, Calendar end) {
    List<DateRange> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Calendar cal = (Calendar) start.clone();
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(start.get(Calendar.YEAR), start.get(Calendar.MONTH), start.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, (cal.getFirstDayOfWeek() - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 7) % 7);
    while (cal.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
        Calendar weekStart = (Calendar) cal.clone();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        Calendar weekEnd = (Calendar) cal.clone();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        result.add(new DateRange(weekStart, weekEnd));
    }
    return result;
}
```

```java
public final class DateRange {
    private final Calendar start;
    private final Calendar end;

    public DateRange(Calendar start, Calendar end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Calendar getStart() {
        return (Calendar) this.start.clone();
    }
    public Calendar getEnd() {
        return (Calendar) this.end.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(this.start.getTime()) + " - " +
               dateFormat.format(this.end.getTime());
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
test(2020,12,13, 2021,2,7, Locale.US);
test(2020,12,13, 2021,2,7, Locale.GERMANY);
```

```java
static void test(int startYear, int startMonth, int startDay, int endYear, int endMonth, int endDay, Locale locale) {
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    start.clear();
    end.clear();
    start.set(startYear, startMonth - 1, startDay);
    end.set(endYear, endMonth - 1, endDay);
    List<DateRange> weeks = weeksCovering(start, end);
    System.out.println(new DateRange(start, end) + ":");
    for (DateRange week : weeks)
        System.out.println("  " + week);
}
```

*Output*

```
Sun, Dec 13, 2020 - Sun, Feb 7, 2021:
  Sun, Dec 13, 2020 - Sat, Dec 19, 2020
  Sun, Dec 20, 2020 - Sat, Dec 26, 2020
  Sun, Dec 27, 2020 - Sat, Jan 2, 2021
  Sun, Jan 3, 2021 - Sat, Jan 9, 2021
  Sun, Jan 10, 2021 - Sat, Jan 16, 2021
  Sun, Jan 17, 2021 - Sat, Jan 23, 2021
  Sun, Jan 24, 2021 - Sat, Jan 30, 2021
  Sun, Jan 31, 2021 - Sat, Feb 6, 2021
  Sun, Feb 7, 2021 - Sat, Feb 13, 2021
Sun, Dec 13, 2020 - Sun, Feb 7, 2021:
  Mon, Dec 7, 2020 - Sun, Dec 13, 2020
  Mon, Dec 14, 2020 - Sun, Dec 20, 2020
  Mon, Dec 21, 2020 - Sun, Dec 27, 2020
  Mon, Dec 28, 2020 - Sun, Jan 3, 2021
  Mon, Jan 4, 2021 - Sun, Jan 10, 2021
  Mon, Jan 11, 2021 - Sun, Jan 17, 2021
  Mon, Jan 18, 2021 - Sun, Jan 24, 2021
  Mon, Jan 25, 2021 - Sun, Jan 31, 2021
  Mon, Feb 1, 2021 - Sun, Feb 7, 2021
```

Notice how it adjusts correctly to the week definition of the `Locale` identified by the starting calendar object.

---

#### Using newer Java 8 Time API

```java
static List<DateRange> weeksCovering(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, WeekFields weekFields) {
    List<DateRange> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    LocalDate date = start.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(weekFields.getFirstDayOfWeek()));
    while (date.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
        LocalDate weekStart = date;
        date = date.plusDays(6);
        LocalDate weekEnd = date;
        date = date.plusDays(1);
        result.add(new DateRange(weekStart, weekEnd));
    }
    return result;
}
```

```java
public final class DateRange {
    private final LocalDate start;
    private final LocalDate end;

    public DateRange(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public LocalDate getStart() {
        return this.start;
    }
    public LocalDate getEnd() {
        return this.end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d, uuuu");
        return dateFormat.format(this.start) + " - " + dateFormat.format(this.end);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
test(2020,12,13, 2021,2,7, Locale.US);
test(2020,12,13, 2021,2,7, Locale.GERMANY);
```

```java
static void test(int startYear, int startMonth, int startDay, int endYear, int endMonth, int endDay, Locale locale) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(endYear, endMonth, endDay);
    List<DateRange> weeks = weeksCovering(start, end, WeekFields.of(locale));
    System.out.println(new DateRange(start, end) + ":");
    for (DateRange week : weeks)
        System.out.println("  " + week);
}
```

*Output*

```
Sun, Dec 13, 2020 - Sun, Feb 7, 2021:
  Sun, Dec 13, 2020 - Sat, Dec 19, 2020
  Sun, Dec 20, 2020 - Sat, Dec 26, 2020
  Sun, Dec 27, 2020 - Sat, Jan 2, 2021
  Sun, Jan 3, 2021 - Sat, Jan 9, 2021
  Sun, Jan 10, 2021 - Sat, Jan 16, 2021
  Sun, Jan 17, 2021 - Sat, Jan 23, 2021
  Sun, Jan 24, 2021 - Sat, Jan 30, 2021
  Sun, Jan 31, 2021 - Sat, Feb 6, 2021
  Sun, Feb 7, 2021 - Sat, Feb 13, 2021
Sun, Dec 13, 2020 - Sun, Feb 7, 2021:
  Mon, Dec 7, 2020 - Sun, Dec 13, 2020
  Mon, Dec 14, 2020 - Sun, Dec 20, 2020
  Mon, Dec 21, 2020 - Sun, Dec 27, 2020
  Mon, Dec 28, 2020 - Sun, Jan 3, 2021
  Mon, Jan 4, 2021 - Sun, Jan 10, 2021
  Mon, Jan 11, 2021 - Sun, Jan 17, 2021
  Mon, Jan 18, 2021 - Sun, Jan 24, 2021
  Mon, Jan 25, 2021 - Sun, Jan 31, 2021
  Mon, Feb 1, 2021 - Sun, Feb 7, 2021
```

Notice how it adjusts correctly to the week definition of the `Locale` identified by the starting calendar object.